# Establecer un USER_AGENT en una aplicacion android ,¿Es el mismo para HTTP?

Tags: java, android, http

Estoy intentando establecer el USER_AGENT en una aplicación Android , para que navegue , con el que yo le indique. Estoy usando la siguiente lineas de código :

```
 public void setUserAgent(){
      DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
      http.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "UserAgentPropio");
        Log.e("","");
        Log.e("USER AGENT : " + System.getProperty("http.agent"),"");
        Log.e("","");
 }
```

La cuestión realmente ramifica en dos :

1. Primera ¿Es lo mismo el USER_AGENT que es usa en HTTP y el que se
   aplica en Android? , mi pregunta proviene de que , en Android se usa
   para navegar en el WebView un User_Agent en concreto , pero se puede
   usar otro para navegar por internet.
2. Y la pregunta Que tengo como principal.

Cuando hago el `System.getProperty(...)` me detecta otro distinto , lo cual no sé si lo estoy detectando de la forma indicada.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comentario importante, las clases de Apache estan marcadas como obsoletas:

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

ahora se recomienda usar **[HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)**

---

Para definir un `User-Agent` a tu conexión usando `DefaultHttpClient`  es :

```
DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
http.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "<Mi USER-AGENT>");
```

Si usas **[UrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html)** ([HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) es subclase), se define de esta forma:

```
URLConnection conn = new URL("http://...").openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("User-agent", "<Mi USER-AGENT>");
conn.connect();
```

---

> Primera ¿Es lo mismo el USER_AGENT que es usa en HTTP y el que se
>   aplica en Android? , mi pregunta proviene de que , en Android se usa
>   para navegar en el WebView un User_Agent en concreto , pero se puede
>   usar otro para navegar por internet.

Cuando defines otro User-Agent estas sobreescribiendo  esta propiedad y puedes navegar sin problema a menos que al realizar la petición tengas configurado un determinado User-Agent para permitirte navegar.

> Y la pregunta Que tengo como principal. Cuando hago el
>   System.getProperty(...) me detecta otro distinto , lo cual no sé si lo
>   estoy detectando de la forma indicada.

**Por medio de `System.getProperty("http.agent")` obtienes el User-Agent default.**

El cual puedes sobreescribir a tu conexión.

```
http.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT,
                                System.getProperty("http.agent"));
```

Tu debes decidir cual necesitas, el default o sobreescribir otro:

```
http.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "<Mi USER-AGENT>");
```

Comment: Perfecto Gracias , no es posible explicarlo mejor.

Comment: Un saludo @CodeNoob !